# Not seeing json file under contracts after compiling a contract on Brownie

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, brownie

Could someone please help on an issue, where I'm not getting a json file after I compile the contract in brownie..It just says

Brownie v1.19.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at Simple_Storage/build/contracts

But there is no JSON file.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see a "cache" folder in your project after compiling? The .json file should be there